# Put objects inside canvas when dragging

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got following codes from this link https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/12/19/715-using-the-thumb-control-to-drag-objects-on-a-canvas/

```
<Canvas>
    <Thumb Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.ZIndex="99"  DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Width="60" Height="60" Source="Crown.jpg"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
    <Thumb Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="60" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Width="80" Height="100" Source="HenryII.jpg"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
    <Thumb Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="180" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Label Content="Westminster, 19-Dec-1154"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
</Canvas>
```

C#

```
private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    UIElement thumb = e.Source as UIElement;

    Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
    Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);
}
```

With this code you are able to drag objects out of to the `Canvas`.

I don't want objects can be dragged out of to the `Canvas`.

Comment: you should compare `left` and `top` of thumb with `0` and canvas's `width` and `height` before changing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your eventHandler to check for the bounds this will prevent your control form leaving the canvas

```
    private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement thumb = e.Source as UIElement; //find thumb
        Canvas AccessibleArea = ((sender as Control).Parent as Canvas); //find parent Canvas
        if (!(Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange > AccessibleArea.ActualWidth - (sender as Control).ActualWidth) //do not pass right maximus
            && !((Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange) <= 0))                                                     //do not pass left minimum
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
        }
        if (!(Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange > AccessibleArea.ActualHeight - (sender as Control).ActualHeight) // do not pass bottom maximum
            && !((Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange) <= 0))                                                       //do not pass top minimum
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);
        }
    }
```